# OpenStack Wallaby Neutron unable to update Designate zone

Tags: openstack, openstack-neutron

So … I'm trying to get neutron to update designate zones.
There initially wasn't any issue with OpenStack Victoria, but trying to update to (or install a fresh) OpenStack Wallaby turned this into a dead-end.

I've deployed both OpenStack Victoria and OpenStack Wallaby the exact same way with kolla-ansible, some configuration changes but for the neutron and designate configuration there hasn't been any changes - so regular old neutron with linuxbridge and designate with bundled bind9 server.

Set the network_vlan_ranges in order to create a vlan-network instead of a VXLAN later on for testing.
`ml2_conf.ini` in `/etc/kolla/config/neutron` is set to

```
[ml2_type_vlan]
network_vlan_ranges = physnet1
```

Commands used:

```
kolla-ansible -i all-in-one bootstrap-servers
kolla-ansible -i all-in-one deploy
kolla-ansible -i all-in-one post-deploy
source /etc/kolla/admin-openrc.sh
init-runonce
openstack zone create "virt.xc." --email "post@xc"
```

Deleted the demo-net and router from init-runonce through Horizon, then recreated them as VLAN in the Horizon-Admin section to not hit this requirement:

> network types VLAN, GRE, VXLAN or GENEVE, the segmentation ID must be outside the ranges assigned to project networks

Set the DNS-domain for `demo-net` to `virt.xc.` by `openstack network set demo-net --dns-domain "virt.xc."`.

```
kolla_base_distro: "ubuntu"
kolla-install_type: "source"
enable_haproxy: "no"
enable_designate: "yes"
enable_neutron_provider_segments: "yes"
enable_neutron_segments: "yes"
neutron_plugin_agent: "linuxbridge"
```

Running

```
openstack server create \\
    --image cirros \\
    --flavor m1.tiny \\
    --key-name mykey \\
    --network demo-net \\
    demo1
```

on OpenStack Victoria deployed with git kolla-ansible stable/victoria works fine and creates an A-record of `demo1.virt.xc.`.

Wallaby (deployed with git kolla-ansible stable/wallaby) however straight up refuses to create an A-record in the `virt.xc.`-zone for the newly created VM `demo1`. It is just never created.

All is done in an Ubuntu 20.04-VM with 12 GiB memory, 4 cpus and nested virtualization enabled, for an all-in-one-deployment before migrating my 4-node cluster.

Am I missing something here? I can provide logs and additional configuration files (from `kolla-ansible -i all-in-one genconfig`) if necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As was discussed in the Launchpad bug tracker [here (1954384)](https://bugs.launchpad.net/neutron/+bug/1954384), this has been introduced in Wallaby as

```
[ml2_type_vlan]
network_vlan_ranges = physnet1
```

now ([neutron-lib changeset (779515)](https://review.opendev.org/c/openstack/neutron-lib/+/779515)) registers for vlan range `1..4094` instead of `[]`, which makes Neutron automatically not register that network in DNS.
Resolution is creating a really small project tenant network vlan range (`physnet1:1:2`) or use `subnet-dns-publish-fixed-ip` instead with `openstack subnet set subnet-name --dns-publish-fixed-ip`.